# setcookie in within the domain

Tags: php, cookies, set

I suffer already about 2 days setcookie, if you can help me, thanks!
My question is this is part of setting the language contained in the settings.php file and it looks like this ...

```
$language = "english";

    if(!isset($_COOKIE["language"]))
        setcookie("language", "english", time()+(60*60*24*365));
    else
        $language = $_COOKIE["language"];

    if($_GET['language']=="english" || $_GET['language']=="serbian"){
        setcookie("language", $_GET['language'], time()+(60*60*24*365));
        $language =  $_GET['language'];
    }

    if($language == "english")
    {
        include("template/language/english.php");
    }
    else if($language == "serbian")
    {
        include("template/language/serbian.php");
    }
```

When I use it just puts me in a language that the folder I selected language but not the other, if you can help out as when in one folder change language to change it for all the folders that are on this site

Comment: Add a / in your setcookie function

Comment: Your conditional statements are also missing curly braces **{}** I hv edited my ans, check if that works

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  setcookie("language", $_GET['language'], time()+(60*60*24*365),"/");
```

---

```
$language = "english";

    if(!isset($_COOKIE["language"]))
      {  setcookie("language", "english", time()+(60*60*24*365),"/");}
    else
      {  $language = $_COOKIE["language"];}

    if     ($_GET['language']=="english" || $_GET['language']=="serbian"){
        setcookie("language", $_GET['language'], time()+(60*60*24*365),"/");}
        $language =  $_GET['language'];


    if($language == "english")
    {
        include("template/language/english.php");
    }
    else if($language == "serbian")
    {
        include("template/language/serbian.php");
    }
```

Comment: Again the language is set only in public_html but not in other folders that are in it

EDIT

Maybe if another folder to be added ../templates/language/

Comment: When I put this does not read any language ... others just blank where I put the codes for language ...

EDIT

You're wrong part of the code should be like this here

`setcookie("language", $_GET['language'], time()+(60*60*24*365),"/");
        $language =  $_GET['language'];}`

Comment: I do not understand? if you can handle this?

Comment: @markosamp I am getting confused, the code you posted works fine for me, Idk why its not working there....May be theres something wrong with the form..